# Call .php page on Intranet (Private) Server from Internet Server (Public)

Tags: php, perl

So I am not even sure if this is possible or not, and I could not find anything on it.

I have a custom built online ordering system from which customers are able to order deli items. This page is located on, Server1 which is a Public Facing server.

On Server2, an internal company server, have a php page created which constructs the 'Order Form' (looks in database for un-printed orders) and then sends the results/arguments to a perl file which prints/sends the form to the specified location (multiple locations for pick-up).

I have a scheduled task that runs on Server2, which runs the php file.

What I want to do is be able to kick off that php file on Server2, from Server1 when a person submits an order. I want this to run outside the normal scheduled task.

I can't use cURL because the internal server2 does not have a URL that can be sent to, as it is internal only.

Any ideas or work arounds/hacks that may be able to accomplish this?

Edit: (Process Flow)

Server1 (Public Web Server) creates entries for orders in Server3 (Internal Database Server) when users submit an order. Server2 php file (scheduled task) queries Server3 Database for non-printed orders and prints them.

Comment: You should be able to use cURL with the server's IP address - IP addresses can be part of URLs :)

Comment: I sure hope you can't cURL to an "internal" server. If you can, it isn't internal and you have HUGE security issues going on.

Comment: Yeah, the internal server doesn't have an IP Address that is available externally. So nothing to cURL to :(

Comment: you cannot (in principle) touch the internal server from the public facing one. The big question is can you get to the public facing server from the internal one? If you can, then setup an api-like app on the public server that serves the orders submitted, then you internal server will just poll your public server api and use the info it gets back to do what you want it to.

Comment: Right now, the php page on the internal server is somewhat doing that already. When an order is placed on the external public server, it goes into a table in the database as submitted but not printed. The php page on the internal server queries the database every xx minutes for orders that are submitted but not printed, and subsequently processes and sends them to the perl script to get printed.

Comment: So if you can get to the data, why is this not working again?

Comment: Right now, the only way it is printing, is by running the task on the internal server which checks for orders that have not printed. This page is located on the internal server, so I cannot call/process it from the External Web Server. I wanted to make it so that when a person submits an order, it would kick off this page outside its normal scheduled task run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup Server2 can always access Server1, but not the other way around.  You would like you "push" data from Server1 to Server2 which is not possible.  I can think of 2 categories of solutions:

1. Polling.  Create a "private" php file on Server1 which has a list of new orders.  Server2 will periodically check or "poll" this list and receive new orders.  For this to be secure you should use HTTPS and use a secret shared key or password.  Server2 can do a POST request once it has received the order to let Server1 know that the order has been handled.
2. A 3rd party service or API which is on the public internet and therefor both servers can access.  A few services come to mind.

   - Pusher: http://pusher.com/docs/server_libraries  Pusher allows for real time "push" notifications to devices behind firewalls.
   - Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other  Server1 could create an order "file" and put it in a private dropbox folder.  Then Server2 can read and delete this file when it's done with the order.

There are other services similar to pusher which may also solve your needs:  http://www.quora.com/What-are-alternatives-to-pusher-com

Comment: Ah, neither of the servers actually access each other directly. Server1 (Public Web Server) creates entries for orders in Server3 (Internal Database Server). Server2 queries Server3 Database for non-printed orders and prints them. I guess I should have specified better. I will definitely look into your suggestions. If not, it will have to just work as is (it runs/checks every 5 mins anyway), just my supervisor wants it to also process every time someone submits (outside of the every 5 min task).